# Execute smart contract on my own blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I developed my own **blockchain** and **crypto** like bitcoin, and now i want to develop smart contracts and import them and **execute**(when a condition is true) them on **my blockchain**, this smart contract will get some information from a web service and **trigger a transaction**(payement by my crypto) on my blockchain, it have been a long time that i searched but i don't found how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin uses Script Language for smart contracts and execute conditions, it depends on complexity of your demands, you can read more: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script
and there is an excellent explanation on this YouTube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Fa04MnURhw